# Remove a class inside the class to prevent to close a modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have several modals.
Each modal closes when clicked.

Now I want to use `<summary>` (which opens and closes on click) inside a modal.
Example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp

Is it possible to remove a class in some arreas inside the class?
So I want to prevent close the modal by clicking in the `<summary>`.

```
<div class="close_modal_onclick"> 
    <span> content1 </span>
    <span> content2 </span>
    <span class="do_not_close_modal_onclick"> content3 with <details> </span>
    <span> content4 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this flagged `php`?

Comment: You certainly can remove a css class by means of javascript, but that is hardly what you want to do. Instead you want to override the settings you defined depending on that class with a more specialized rule for the inner class.